# WordPress - escape html in _n_noop

Tags: wordpress

I need to escape all strings in my theme. But I cannot find the alternative for _n_noop(). How it is possible to escape html in _n_noop()?

```
_n_noop(
    /* translators: 1: plugin name(s). */
    'This theme requires the following plugin: %1$s.',
    'This theme requires the following plugins: %1$s.',
    'textdomain'
)
```

Comment: I think I don't get your question but... `_n_noop(esc_html('This theme requires the following plugin: %1$s.'), esc_html('This theme requires the following plugins: %1$s.'), 'textdomain')`

Answer (score 0):

_n_noop( string $singular, string $plural, string $domain = null )
Registers plural strings in POT file, but does not translate them.

Use when you want to keep structures with translatable plural strings

```
$message = _n_noop( '%s post', '%s posts', 'text-domain' );
...
printf( translate_nooped_plural( $message, $count, 'text-domain' ), number_format_i18n( $count ) );
```